# Moving Files on Mac to Harddrive Stops Halfway and Files Disappear

Tags: mac

Tried to move (cut and paste, not copy) files from my Mac Finder to my WD harddrive.

The transfer stopped halfway, and some appear as sort of "ghost files" on my harddrive (0KB, translucent (see screenshot)). To my horror the original files on my Mac also disappeared.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/85wxyw

Why does this happen and is there way to recover the files?

Answer (score 0):

Computers don't actually just forget things. They put files in a state where they are allowed to be overwritten. I am not sure why that is happening. It could be because the hard drive is full. Anyways, you can most likely find a program on the Internet that'll take it out of the overwritten state. To check your hard drives storage, simply ctrl-click on the hard drive, and select get info. It should say the storage on that screen. The original rip files probably disappeared because you cut them.

Comment: Hi Wilson thx for answer. what does taking out of the overwritten state of a computer entail? Will i be able to recover the files then?

Comment: Honestly, I do not know. I just know it is possible. You'll probably need a professional to do it because it involves getting files from a hard drive without using the OS.